# Ubuntu 13.10 and nVidia video adapter

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors

I have a system76 Bonobo laptop, which has a GeForce GT 560M.

When the laptop comes back from suspend, the video is weird, I need to power cycle the laptop to have it functional.  So I suspect a problem with video driver.  Did I need to install other video drivers or just keep those installed in 13.10?

My setup use a dual screen, but I would like to have dynamic reconfiguration when I plug or unplug my external monitor.

Answer (score 0):

The best place to ask this question would be on the support forums for System76.

http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=341